# Hide table that is created by click-event on leaflet map after data is updated in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have the shiny app below in which the user uploads a file (here I just put the dt in a reactive function) and from there he can choose which columns he wants to display as `selectInput()` via a `pickerInput()`. Then he should be able to click on `Update2` and see the map.

The user should also be able to update the `depth` values by multiplying  all of them with the `numericInput()` `value1` and create a new `sliderInput()` and therefore update the dataframe that is displayed in the table as well. These changes should be applied only when the user clicks on `Update2` actionbutton.

When I click on a specific point I get a table below the map with relative data. The issue is that when I do another action,for example update the map or something, this table remains there while I want it to be disappeared and re-appeared when I click on a point again.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
# ui object

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("inputp1"),
            #Add the output for new pickers
            uiOutput("pickers"),
            numericInput("num", label = ("value"), value = 1),
            actionButton("button2", "Update 2")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            leafletOutput("map"),
            tableOutput("myTable")
            
            
            
        )
    )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    
    dt <- reactive({
        
        dt<-data.frame(quakes)
        dt$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dt))
        dt
    })
    
    observe({
        DF1$data <- dt()
    })

    output$inputp1 <- renderUI({
        pickerInput(
            inputId = "p1",
            label = "Select Column headers",
            choices = colnames( dt()),
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
        )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$p1, {
        #Create the new pickers
        output$pickers<-renderUI({
            dt1 <- DF1$data
            div(lapply(input$p1, function(x){
                if (is.numeric(dt1[[x]])) {
                    sliderInput(inputId=x, label=x, min=min(dt1[[x]]), max=max(dt1[[x]]), value=c(min(dt1[[x]]),max(dt1[[x]])))
                }else { # if (is.factor(dt1[[x]])) {
                    selectInput(
                        inputId = x,       # The col name of selected column
                        label = x,         # The col label of selected column
                        choices = dt1[,x], # all rows of selected column
                        multiple = TRUE
                    )
                }
                
            }))
        })
    })
    dt2 <- eventReactive(input$button2, {
        req(input$num)
        
        dt <- DF1$data ## here you can provide the user input data read inside this observeEvent or recently modified data DF1$data
        dt$depth<-dt$depth*isolate(input$num)
        
        dt
    })
    observe({DF1$data <- dt2()})
    observeEvent(input$button2, {
        req(input$p1, sapply(input$p1, function(x) input[[x]]))
        dt_part <- dt2()
        colname <- colnames(dt2())
        for (colname in input$p1) {
            if (!is.null(input[[colname]][[1]]) && is.numeric(input[[colname]][[1]])) {
                dt_part <- subset(dt_part, (dt_part[[colname]] >= input[[colname]][[1]]) & dt_part[[colname]] <= input[[colname]][[2]])
            }else {
                if (!is.null(input[[colname]])) {
                    dt_part <- subset(dt_part, dt_part[[colname]] %in% input[[colname]])
                }
            }
        }
        
    output$map<-renderLeaflet({input$button2
        if (input$button2){
        leaflet(dt_part) %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
            setView( 178, -20, 5 ) %>%
            addHeatmap(
                lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, intensity = ~mag,
                blur = 20, max = 0.05, radius = 15
            ) %>% 
            addCircleMarkers(lng = dt_part$long, lat = dt_part$lat, layerId = dt_part$depth,
                             fillOpacity = 0, weight = 0,
                             popup = paste("ID:", dt_part$ID, "<br>",
                                           "Depth:", dt_part$depth, "<br>",
                                           "Stations:", dt_part$stations),
                             labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE)) 
        }
        else{
            return(NULL)
        }
    })
    
   
    })
    
    
    
   
    data <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker=NULL)
    
    # observe the marker click info and print to console when it is changed.
    observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
        dt_part <- dt2()
        
        print("observed map_marker_click")
        data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click
        print(data$clickedMarker)
        output$myTable <- renderTable({
            return(
                subset(dt_part,depth == data$clickedMarker$id)
            )
        })
    })
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think the easiest way to do this is to use the package `shinyjs` there you can use the jQuery functions to hide and show objects you want. Please note that you have to activate shinyjs with the function `useShinyjs()` inthe UI part aswell

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),# Set up shinyjs
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("inputp1"),
      #Add the output for new pickers
      uiOutput("pickers"),
      numericInput("num", label = ("value"), value = 1),
      actionButton("button2", "Update 2")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map"),
      tableOutput("myTable")
      
      
      
    )
  )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  dt <- reactive({
    
    dt<-data.frame(quakes)
    dt$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dt))
    dt
  })
  
  observe({
    DF1$data <- dt()
  })
  
  output$inputp1 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "p1",
      label = "Select Column headers",
      choices = colnames( dt()),
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$p1, {
    #Create the new pickers
    output$pickers<-renderUI({
      dt1 <- DF1$data
      div(lapply(input$p1, function(x){
        if (is.numeric(dt1[[x]])) {
          sliderInput(inputId=x, label=x, min=min(dt1[[x]]), max=max(dt1[[x]]), value=c(min(dt1[[x]]),max(dt1[[x]])))
        }else { # if (is.factor(dt1[[x]])) {
          selectInput(
            inputId = x,       # The col name of selected column
            label = x,         # The col label of selected column
            choices = dt1[,x], # all rows of selected column
            multiple = TRUE
          )
        }
        
      }))
    })
  })
  dt2 <- eventReactive(input$button2, {
    req(input$num)
    
    dt <- DF1$data ## here you can provide the user input data read inside this observeEvent or recently modified data DF1$data
    dt$depth<-dt$depth*isolate(input$num)
    
    dt
  })
  observe({DF1$data <- dt2()})
  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    req(input$p1, sapply(input$p1, function(x) input[[x]]))
    dt_part <- dt2()
    colname <- colnames(dt2())
    shinyjs::runjs("console.log('hiding table')")
    shinyjs::runjs("$('#myTable').hide()")
    for (colname in input$p1) {
      if (!is.null(input[[colname]][[1]]) && is.numeric(input[[colname]][[1]])) {
        dt_part <- subset(dt_part, (dt_part[[colname]] >= input[[colname]][[1]]) & dt_part[[colname]] <= input[[colname]][[2]])
      }else {
        if (!is.null(input[[colname]])) {
          dt_part <- subset(dt_part, dt_part[[colname]] %in% input[[colname]])
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    
    output$map<-renderLeaflet({input$button2
      if (input$button2){
        leaflet(dt_part) %>%
          addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
          setView( 178, -20, 5 ) %>%
          addHeatmap(
            lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, intensity = ~mag,
            blur = 20, max = 0.05, radius = 15
          ) %>% 
          addCircleMarkers(lng = dt_part$long, lat = dt_part$lat, layerId = dt_part$depth,
                           fillOpacity = 0, weight = 0,
                           popup = paste("ID:", dt_part$ID, "<br>",
                                         "Depth:", dt_part$depth, "<br>",
                                         "Stations:", dt_part$stations),
                           labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE)) 
      }
      else{
        return(NULL)
      }
    })
  })
  
  
  
  
  data <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker=NULL)
  
  # observe the marker click info and print to console when it is changed.
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    dt_part <- dt2()
    print("observed map_marker_click")
    data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click
    print(data$clickedMarker)
    output$myTable <- renderTable({
      shinyjs::runjs("console.log('showing table')")
      shinyjs::runjs("$('#myTable').show()")
      return(
        subset(dt_part,depth == data$clickedMarker$id)
      )
    })
  })
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027378/shinyjs-is-not-working-properly-due-to-shiny-reactivity